# Flask - b' text appears before request.data results

Tags: python-3.x, python-2.7, flask, python-requests, facebook-access-token

So I for a while I was running my application on **Python's Localhost** for debugging reasons, but now I desperately want to make my **Flask** application run on my **Apache Localhost**. I have configured Ubuntu on Vagrant to run the application on Apache and the only thing that does not work right now is the Facebook Sign-In. While my Google Sign-in method works fine on both Python's Localhost and on Apache, my Facebook Sign-in method **only works on Python's Localhost and NOT on Apache's Localhost for some reason**.

Specifically, in my **fbconnect() method** that preforms the fb sign-in functionality, when the code reaches my **4th print**( *print("4. FB http request results: %s" % result)* ) of the given code block *(scroll down for the block of code)*, the message given off by the 4th print is **this error**:

```
4. FB http request results: b'{"error":{"message":"Invalid OAuth access token.","type":"OAuthException","code":190,"fbtrace_id":"AjWGMxq54MULV0sCpjpW2DT"}}'
```

I don't know what the **b'** is doing there *(it appears right at the start of the error message)* and **how to remove it**, but it also appears in the 1st print( _print("1. Access token: %s " % access_token)_ ) :

```
1. Access token: b'EAAE7dgXeMUup...'
```

and it **does NOT appear** in the **2nd** or the **3rd** print:

```
2. App ID: 3425...
3. App secret: 75a2...
```

I think that the problem is caused by those **b'** since they do not appear in my prints when I run the app on my **Python Localhost** and they also do not appear in the **2nd** or **3rd** prints on Apache, but **I'm not sure** as they might be appearing because the print output is somehow changed when I write out the messages in a 'print.log' file, since Apache doesn't actually print out messages to the terminal like Python's Localhost does.
Here's my **fbconnect() method**:

```
def fbconnect():

    ''' Validate state token, by confirming that the token that the client sends
    to the server matches the token that the server sent to the client. This
    round-trip verification helps ensure that the user is making the request
    not a malicious script. Using the request.args.get() method, we examine
    the state token passed in by the ajax request and compare with the state
    of the login_session. If these 2 do NOT match, we create a response of an
    invalid state token and return this message to the client. '''

    if request.args.get('state') != login_session['state']:
        response = make_response(json.dumps('Invalid state parameter.'), 401)
        response.headers['Content-Type'] = 'application/json'
        return response
    access_token = request.data
    print("1. Access token: %s " % access_token)

    # Get Facebook app ID.
    app_id = json.loads(open('/vagrant/Inhinito/fb_client_secrets.json', 'r').read())['web']['app_id']
    print("2. App ID: %s " % app_id)

    # Get Facebook app secret.
    app_secret = json.loads(open('/vagrant/Inhinito/fb_client_secrets.json', 'r').read())['web']['app_secret']
    print("3. App secret: %s " % app_secret)

    # Make http request to the Facebook API.
    url = "https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?client_id=%s" % (app_id)
    url += "&client_secret=%s&grant_type=fb_exchange_token" % (app_secret)
    url += "&fb_exchange_token=%s" % (access_token)
    http = httplib2.Http()
    result = http.request(url, 'GET')[1]
    print("4. FB http request results: %s" % result)

    ....
```

Here's the correct output that I get from Python's Localhost:

```
1. Access token: EAgE7...
4. FB http request results: {"access_token":"EAgE7...","token_type":"bearer","expires_in":5183999}
```

Comment: Are you sure you want to be using `request.data`-- that's the 'raw' data of the request, you probably want `request.form["access_token"]` or similar.  the `b` indicates it's bytes. Python can turn that back into a string if it know how it was encoded-- it looks like you're sending it as UTF8 so you can decode that using something like `access_token.decode('UTF-8')`.  I believe if you just used `request.form["access_token"]` it would already know and handle that decoding.

Comment: @Doobeh you're right that was the problem, found out what was wrong around the time you posted you're answer here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6269765/what-does-the-b-character-do-in-front-of-a-string-literal

If you use request.form["access_token"] for some reason it returns:
```Bad Request
The browser (or proxy) sent a request that this server could not understand```
but using ```access_token.decode('UTF-8')``` works :/ I wonder why...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As Doobeh mentioned in the comments the solution is to decode the data sent by the client-side to UTF-8. This is a **Python2 vs Python3** issue explained in detail [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6269765/what-does-the-b-character-do-in-front-of-a-string-literal).

The **b' '** apparently is used to indicate the string is **binary**, as opposed to Unicode.
The solution is to use
`access_token = request.data.decode('UTF-8')`
Instead of
`access_token = request.data` and 
`http.request(url, 'GET')[1].decode('UTF-8')` instead of `http.request(url, 'GET')[1]`.